# A $k$-regular tree is unique

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to prove that a $k$-regular tree is unique upto isomorphism. Clearly except for the trivial cases $K_1$ or $K_2$ any such tree must be infinite, for if it had $n$ vertices then $k=\frac{2(n-1)}{n}$ (by the handshaking lemma and the fact that in a tree the number of edges is one less then the number of vertices). Since $(n-1,n)=1$ so $n\mid 2$ which forces the trivial cases.

Furthermore it is evident that such a tree $T$ may be constructed by taking a vertex $v$, giving it $k$-neighbors, then giving each of the neighbors a further $k-1$ neighbors, and so on. What is not evident to me is as to why every $k$-regular tree will be isomorphic to $T$. Can I simply construct an isomorphism like this: Pick any vertex $x$. Correspond it to $v$. Arbitrarily correspond each of the $k$ neighbors of $x$ to the neighbors of $v$ in a one to one fashion. Continue doing so. Is this is a valid way to describe an isomorphism?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let G be another k-regular tree. choose a vertex in $G$ and map it to the 'base' of $T$. Map its neighbours to the neighbours of the base. Map the neighbours of those neighbours to the neighbours of the neighbours. Repeat until you have an isomorphism!

In short, your construction contains within it a proof of uniqueness...

Comment: Oh! I was thinking the same. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Out of curiosity what axiom of set theory justifies that this indeed is an isomorphism?

Comment: I'm not really a set theorist, but I suppose it is ultimately an inductive proof, where the induction is on 'distance from the basepoint'. So it's somewhere in the definition of the natural numbers.